# Tick labels at regular intervals

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I would like to replicate the following heatmap, and I'm quite close. I'm new to python and I don't get the axes and the coloring right.

```
def fun(C_1, C_2):
    return np.multiply(C_1, C_2)

C_1 = np.linspace(-2,2,100)
C_2 = np.linspace(-2,2,100)

# filling the heatmap, value by value
fun_map = np.empty((C_1.size, C_2.size))
for i in range(C_1.size):
    for j in range(C_2.size):
        fun_map[i,j] = fun(C_1[i], C_2[j])

sns.heatmap(fun_map)
```

This produces the following plot. What I don't know is how to get the axis right, i.e. `C_1` and `C_2` instead of the indices.

And also, how do I only show the `0.5` steps, i.e. `-2, -1.5, etc.`?

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the ticks on both axes you could either use `set` and specify the `xticklabels` and `yticklabels`. For the numerical tick labels to be at regular intervals though, we'll need to work a little on the label sequences. Here's one approach:

```
def show_at_intervals(seq, interval, decimals=1):
    x = np.copy(seq)
    low, high = x.min(), x.max()
    ar = np.arange(low,high,interval)
    replate_at = np.searchsorted(x, ar)
    new_ticks = np.full(x.shape, '', dtype=f'U{4+decimals}')
    new_ticks[replate_at] = x[replate_at].round(decimals)
    return new_ticks
```

Then just specify the sequences we want on both axes ad the new intervals (note that the outer product can directly be obtained using [`np.multiply.outer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html)):

```
g = sns.heatmap(np.multiply.outer(C_1, C_2), 
                xticklabels=True, yticklabels=True)
_ = g.set(xticklabels = show_at_intervals(C_1, 0.5),
          yticklabels = show_at_intervals(C_1, 0.5))
```

[image]

Or for instance for a spacing of `.5` on the `x-axis` and `0.2` on the `y-axis`:

```
g = sns.heatmap(np.multiply.outer(C_1, C_2))
_ = g.set(xticklabels = show_at_intervals(C_1, .5),
          yticklabels = show_at_intervals(C_2, 0.2))
```

[image]

Comment: Follow-up question, how do I only show the 0.5-steps, i.e. -2, -1.5, etc.?